# Best way to handle multiple functions/scenarios inside an express route?

Tags: node.js, express

I have many endpoints in my express app that have many conditions. I want to find what is the best design pattern for them without repeating myself so much.

This is one of my simpler routes:

```
 router.post('/reset/:token',
    asyncMiddleware(async(req, res, next) => { await reset(req, res, next, pino); })
  );
```

Inside `reset()`I need to check a couple of things, such as:

- If all the required body params are there
- If the email from the decrypted token matches the one from the database
- If the password was saved successfully.

I would like to check those conditions that without having a huge function, but I don't know what is **the best way** to do so.

### Entire Route Code

```
export async function reset(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  if (!email) return res.status(400).json(Error.paramsMissing('email'));

  const user = await userAssociatedWithEmail(req.body.email);
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(501).json(Error.noActiveUserAssociatedWithEmail);
  }

  // Generate token
  const token = await jwt.sign({ email: user.email, id: user.id }, 'shhhhh');
  const emailSent = await sendForgotEmail(token, user);

  if (!emailSent) return res.status(500).json(Error.emailNotSent);
  else return res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Email sent successfully.' });
}
```

### What I would like to do

Final Result I'd like to have

```
export async function reset(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  if (!email) return res.status(400).json(Error.paramsMissing('email'));

  // If error inside userAssociatedWithEmail, I'd like to stop execution and 
  // return res.status(501).json(Error.noActiveUserAssociatedWithEmail) from inside 
  // that function, without having to add an if condition below as exists in the 
  // original code above
  const user = await userAssociatedWithEmail(req.body.email); 

  const token = await jwt.sign({ email: user.email, id: user.id }, 'shhhhh');

  // Again I'd like to return res.status(500).json(Error.emailNotSent) 
  // from inside sendForgotEmail IF there is an error
  const emailSent = await sendForgotEmail(token, user); 

  // If everything is successful, finally I'd return this
  return res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Email sent successfully.' });
}
```

Explanation of the result in word:

I'd like to be able to handle the conditions and scenarios without having to handle it in the main `reset` function  if that's possible (aka, without having to store a response in a variable, check the variable and `return` in the main function in the case of error).

So for example, instead of:

```
  const allParamsAreValid = validParams(token, email, new_password, res);
  if (!allParamsAreValid) return;
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
  validateParams(token, email, new_password, res);
```

And then inside `validateParams()` if a param is missing, I'd force exit the program besides also setting the response with `res.json({})`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Just create shared functions for your common functionality and pass those shared functions the `req` object.  Then, you can just call whichever shared functions you need in any given route.  People tend to forget when writing routes, that you can share code with common functions just like in all your other code.

Comment: Yes I get that I can do that. My issue is that I don't know how to exit the process. Maybe my question is not clear enough. I have the route, which uses the `reset()` function. Then I use `validateParams()`. If the params are not valid and I return `res.json({ message: 'Invalid parameter' })` from INSIDE  `validateParams()`, the code does not **exit**. It continues. And if I have another second res later, I get the error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`.

Comment: Show us the WHOLE sequence of code for the request (all the code involved from beginning to end of the request) and explain exactly where you want the request to stop processing.  The, and only then can we help you.  You aren't showing enough code for us to know how to help.  Also, responding a week later is NOT the way stack overflow works.  You need to engage interactively with those who attempt to help you.  I will be out the rest of the evening, but  can check back later.  If you're not going to add relevant code to your question, it will probably just get closed as unclear.

Comment: I was not receiving any notification on my email that there were replies. I only saw it today. Will keep in mind that I need to respond faster. In any case, I updated the code in the original question. If it's still unclear I will close it. Let me know and thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the `asyncMiddleware` function?  Please show code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all your asynchronous functions that return promises reject their promise with the status and value you want sent.  Then, you can handle that rejected promise in one place:

```
export async function reset(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const email = req.body.email;
        if (!email) return res.status(400).json(Error.paramsMissing('email'));

        // If error inside userAssociatedWithEmail, I'd like to stop execution and 
        // return res.status(501).json(Error.noActiveUserAssociatedWithEmail) from inside 
        // that function, without having to add an if condition below as exists in the 
        // original code above
        const user = await userAssociatedWithEmail(req.body.email); 

        const token = await jwt.sign({ email: user.email, id: user.id }, 'shhhhh');

        // Again I'd like to return res.status(500).json(Error.emailNotSent) 
        // from inside sendForgotEmail IF there is an error
        const emailSent = await sendForgotEmail(token, user); 
        // If everything is successful, finally I'd return this
        res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Email sent successfully.' });

    } catch(e) {
        res.status(e.status || 500).json(e.errData)
    }
}
```

And, then all of your asynchronous functions would reject if they have an error condition and set both `e.status` and `e.errData` on the rejected reason.  That would allow you to have one common error handler and let the `async` function collect any rejected promise into your try/catch for you.  This is meant to be the clean way you handle rejections in a series of `await` calls where you want the whole function to finish.

Then, you also need to make sure your `asyncMiddleware()` function is NOT also sending a response (can't really tell what its purpose is).  You don't show that code, so I can't see what it's doing.

You don't show any code that uses `validateParams()`, but if it was synchronous, then it could just throw an exception with the right fields set on it and the `try/catch` would also catch it just like it would catch the async rejections.

For example:

```
function validateParams(token, email, new_password) {
    let err = new Error();
    err.errData = {status: 'error'};
    if (!token) {
       err.errData.message = 'invalid token';
       throw err;
    }
    if (!email) {
       err.errData = Error.paramsMissing('email');
       throw err;
    }
    if (!new_password) {
       err.errData.message = 'invalid new password');
       throw err;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to, you could also send an error response in `validateParams()`, but I think it's cleaner not to because they you can collect all errors including all your `await` asynchronous  calls in one try/catch in the route handler and frankly, it's a lot more readable and understandable code not to send a response in some function calls, but not in others.  I try to keep all my responses both error and success sent at the same level.  Then, it's really easy to keep track of and to avoid accidentally trying to send multiple responses.

Then, in your route handler, you'd just call `validateParams(...)` just like that.  If it throws, your try/catch would catch it and send the appropriate error.  If no error, then execution would just continue.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted, to handle all errors in the right place. That works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing **res** object to the **validateParams** method, you can do something like this,

```
async function validateParams(token, email, new_password, res) {
  if (token && emal && new_password &&  res) {
    // all values are available
    // perform your desired operation 
  } else {
    // exit from the method and pass info to the client
    return res.json({ message: 'Invalid parameter' });
  }
}
```

In this case, all you have to do is invoking the validateParams.

```
await validateParams(token, email, new_password, res);
```

If there is a missing parameter, the server passes the control to the client immediately. Otherwise, you can perform your operation there.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. 

When I do `return res.json({ message: 'Invalid parameter' });` from inside `validateParams` function it doesn't exit the process. 

So if inside `reset` I have another `res.json({ secondMessage: 'afterfirst' })`, it throws the error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`. The only solution to avoid that that has worked for me is doing the check inside `reset()`, but that's exactly what I would like to avoid.

Any way I can avoid that error? What am I missing?

Comment: In your `reset method`, is there a `res.json({ secondMessage: 'afterfirst' })`? Your pseudo code didn't show that. In that case, you have to return `false` from the reset method.

Comment: The pseudo code does not show that indeed, apologies, but I did mention in the question that I had other conditions after. 

If I return `false` in the reset method I am back to how the code was before and would have to handle it in the `validateParams`, which is what I would like to avoid.